# Kак в JS написать функцию которая ищет в массиве слово которое было введено пользователем в диалоговом окне (prompt)

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты

Имеется массив со множеством объектов (фрукты с различными свойствами).
Пользователю предлагается выбрать фрукт в диалоговом окне (prompt), например название фрукта (яблоко).
Пользователь печатает слово "яблоко"
Kак в JS написать функцию, которая в этом массиве ищет это яблоко (т.е. переменную), которое было введено пользователем в диалоговом окне (prompt) и после нахождения этой переменной выводит его определенное значение (например только цвет этого яблока).

Comment: prompt и find. Предложите своё решение и что не получилось

Comment: К сожалению решения не могу найти. Получается находить только через индекс. Т.е. есть  объекты (такие как этот - let fruit  = { name: 'apple', sorts: [ 'white ', 'red', 'green'],}. Есть массив с этими объектами (let  food = [fruit, vegetables, и т.д.]) . Если пользователю создать promt в котором будет написано - выберите food (0 - fruit, 1 - vegetables, 3 - и т.д.), т.е. он вводит цифру, которая по сути является индексом массива, то все нормально (такую функцию получается сделать). А вот если мне надо передать в функцию не число, а именно слово ( "fruit"), как тогда должна выглядеть функция

Comment: через find всё найдется

Comment: @AleksandrM Код - в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fruits = [
  { name: "plum", color: "blue" },
  { name: "apple", color: "red" },
  { name: "orange", color: "orange" }
];

const input1 = "apple";
const input2 = "pear";

function findFruitColor(name, fruits) {
  return (fruits.find(i => i.name == name) || {}).color;
}

console.log(findFruitColor(input1, fruits));
console.log(findFruitColor(input2, fruits));
```